# dynArch calendar - issue when input field is non date

Tags: javascript

I have been using the dynArch calendar for some time now. Can't say I've explored all the alternatives but I can recommend this one. Its pretty flexible.

I have run into a problem today that selecting a date was suddenly not updating the text control.

Ultimately, the problem seems to be that when the linked text box is blank, the calendar does not update the linked text box on selecting a date. Further testing reveals that any non-date causes the unwanted behavior.

I have verified that this behavior has been lurking in my production code, so its something I need to address.

I have started walking through the js library to see if i can track it down, but thought I would reach out to the collective as well.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please, replicate the bug and post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, the reason I was not seeing the popup was becuase the target text box had an invalid date in it.

I did not research if i could make it pop up a calendar w/ today in it.